# Convert int array to hex array

Tags: java

I have array of int of 200. I want  convert this array to hex array and hex array in to  output as string. How can I do this one

Help appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to convert an `int` array to an array of strings containing the hex representations of the numbers?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have trouble on converting the ints? You should go for an approach on your own before you ask for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Integer.toHexString(num)` method.

E.g.

```
for(int i=0; i < intArray.length; i++){
    stringArray[i] = Integer.toHexString(intArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: This is **not** a valid answer which covers the complete question

Comment: user can use this method in a for loop and can convert whole int array into hex string Array. I think a hint is only required here.

Comment: True! So you should edit your answer to clarify your approach. Ofcourse your answer may lead to the right direction but at this point it is more like a comment.

Comment: OK Ben, thanks for your comment. I have edited my answer to clarify the approach.